# How to solve focal Release' does not have a Release file?

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I am unable to run the apt-get update. Every time I run this command I am getting this error massge. Can someone please help

```
kgo@ws-kgo:~/Documents/side$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                               
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal InRelease                                                              
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                            
Hit:5 https://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                           
Hit:6 https://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                            
Hit:7 https://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                  
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release                                          
Hit:9 https://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                          
Ign:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Ign:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease  
Err:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Err:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Hit:14 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a supported release; so why would it be found in old-releases as per your post?   Only unsupported or EOL releases are found there and whomever moved it there is many years too early.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has *standard* support until 2025-April, and ESM support for a further 5 years before it reaches EOL and gets moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com.  Someone with `sudo` rights has changed it incorrectly on your machine; reverse that change (ie.  it should be http://archive.ubuntu.com/ still)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a supported release; so why would it be found in old-releases as per your post?

Only *unsupported* or EOL releases are found there and whomever moved it there is many years too early.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has *standard* support until 2025-April, and ESM support for a further 5 years before it reaches EOL and gets moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com (*which will occur sometime after 2030-April*)

Someone with `sudo` rights has changed it incorrectly on your machine; reverse that change (ie.  those lines should be http://archive.ubuntu.com/ and **not** http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: you mean to change in the /etc/apt/sources.list ?? Should I replace everything related to  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ in the source list with archive.ubuntu?? @guiverc

Comment: Yeah the lines that currently say "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" as that applies to EOL or *end-of-life* releases such as 12.04, 19.10 etc.   Those lines should read http://archive.ubuntu.com/ as per my answer; ie. only those lines need to be changed.  Changes can be made in GUI or via text editor (I'd use a terminal text editor); note you'll need to elevate your privileges (ie. `sudoedit` can be used for this purpose)

Comment: For me this didn't work. The only solution worked for me was: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem