# Ubuntu sudo apt get update 404 Not Found problem

Tags: 20.04, updates, repository

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
I've been facing an error for 2 days that is, I can't update or upgrade or perform package installs on my system because of the following errors:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                              
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                      
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                               
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-5.1-releases/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                    
Hit:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                         
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                
Ign:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                            
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                           
Ign:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                      
Err:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-gcc-arm-embedded/ppa/ubuntu focal Release                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Hit:17 https://linux-clients.seafile.com/seafile-deb/focal stable InRelease                
Err:18 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Err:19 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.247 80]
Ign:13 https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/gcc-arm-embedded focal InRelease
Err:20 https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/gcc-arm-embedded focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.89.222 443]
Reading package lists... Done
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Why do you have `old-releases` in your sources? Focal is hardly an "old release" ... 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) Your sources.list is messed up. Just reset them, and then re-add any repos your really need after, like for VS Code

Comment: @cocomac No, I try every step but it doesnt work.

Comment: @matigo I dont know :/ how can I solve this?

Comment: If @cocomac's solution did not work, then you will need to open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and fix the issue manually. Focal Fossa is not at all an "old release", so the URL naturally 404s. You will need to replace `old-releases.ubuntu.com` with something logical, like `archive.ubuntu.com` (or the one for your geographical region) 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\*Error\* for Sudo apt-get update on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372928/error-for-sudo-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Do you remember who and why changed "archive" to "old-releases" for supported 20.04 LTS (focal) release? Both team-gcc-arm-embedded and ~terry.guo do not provide packages for 20.04, you have to disable them.

Comment: @N0rbert It's clear that they've updated from an old release to 20.04 using the `sed` command. So, maybe they were on 17.04 and replaced the codename to focal in their sources.list.

Comment: I dont know but my friends have same issue although they have different ubuntu versions (16.04, 18.0 , 20.04). Is this problem cause of the region?

Comment: @gogogo Did you try my answer? What is the result of `apt update` now?

Comment: I did all things I get below lines output:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: @gogogo Great! Seems the problem is solved. You can run `sudo apt update` to look for upgradeable packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: You can use http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu for older versions

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Most of the repositories and PPAs in your `sources.list` are no longer available and are throwing errors. I'd recommend restoring the default repositories.

1. First, restore the default repositories using these commands:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/solution
   cd ~/solution/

   cat << EOF > ~/solution/sources.list
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
   deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
   EOF

   sudo sed -i "s/focal/$(lsb_release -c -s)/" ~/solution/sources.list
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo cp ~/solution/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Remove all the PPAs in your system:

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ~/solution
   ```
3. Update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

All set!

Comment: awesome.. finally this fixed it after almost 2 hours of trying. thank you so much!

Comment: god bless you :))

Comment: At the end of your regimen, it says, "40 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them."   How do I proceed?

Comment: @MichaelLevy you should upgrade those packages, run `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Great! You saved my day

Comment: I'm seeing (many) errors like this `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]` even after patching as described. https://gist.github.com/bsodmike/1e79af133390bc12a5f132a8fa3435f4