# Update from 18.04 to 22.04 fails

Tags: updates, update-manager

Main workflow:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

fails. When following the [Ubuntu sudo apt get update 404 Not Found problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem) answer (replacinf focal with bionic ofc) I get multiple definitions (/var/log/dist-upgrade log:

```
2022-09-15 10:04:28,860 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 0)
2022-09-15 10:04:36,988 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 1)
2022-09-15 10:04:57,516 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:15, W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-i386) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target Contents-deb (restricted/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, W:Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16, E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 2)
2022-09-15 10:04:57,516 ERROR doUpdate() failed completely
2022-09-15 10:04:57,517 DEBUG abort called
```

When deleting the lines created in sources.list by above mentioned thread, leaving just the auto-added lines

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

I get to a different output (same result though):

```
2022-09-15 10:12:26,125 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2022-09-15 10:12:32,086 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 0)
2022-09-15 10:12:42,241 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 1)
2022-09-15 10:12:49,308 ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): 'E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80], E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.'. Retrying (currentRetry: 2)
2022-09-15 10:12:49,308 ERROR doUpdate() failed completely
2022-09-15 10:12:49,308 DEBUG abort called
```

I guess I need to force the manager to not update arm64 packages somehow (my architectur if of course x86, the arm packages are for crosscompiling projects).
I have tried to remove snapd as suggested by some threads here, no help.

Comment: You need an appropriate main, bionic-security, and bionic-updates source for your amd64 architecture. AND you need an appropriate main, bionic-security, and bionic-updates source for your arm64 architecture. Each source for each arch should appear only once (no duplicates). It's that simple. There is no need to "force" anything (forcing means you're doing something wrong). There is no need to remove snapd, which  completely unrelated to apt.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so two things were needed.
Firstly I needed to get the correct valit sources.list (e.g. https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1).
Secondly

```
dpkg --remove-architecture arm64
```

made sure I am not trying to get the ARM packages.
And lastly, after the update manager finished, rebooting any other way than "sudo reboot" did not work. After reboot everything seemed OK.